# Stop chanel posts handling using pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I created a bot to forward msgs from chanel to user if he uses the command start it starts forwarding msgs to the user and if he wants to stop I created a stop command but I didn't know how to stop posts handling of the chanel or remove it

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start","stop"]
def forward_msgs(m):
if m.text[1:]=="start":
@bot.chanel_post_handler(func= lambda mm: true)
def forwarding(mm):
bot.forward_message(m.chat.id, mm.chat.id, mm.id)
elif m.text[1:]=="stop":

(this is the part that I dont know how to complet)